# find parameter for maximize area

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

suppose that we have Cartesian coordinate system.and suppose that we have three point which depend on parameter $t$,where  t belongs  to $(0,1)$;points are

$A(cos(3-t),sin(3-t))$

$B(cos(t),sin(t))$

$C(-cos(t),-sin(t))$

goal: find  $t$ for which  area of triangle $ABC$ is maximum

first of   all,i was thinking that  we  could find length of each side of triangles,for example

$BC=2$

but  what about another sides?we can use determinant formula like here

http://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html

and  goal  will be find maximum determinant,but could we it?also i have calculate length of $AB$,which is equal  $2*cos(t)*cos(3-t)-2*sin(t)*sin(3-t)$ which is i think

$2*cos(\alpha-\beta)$

or in our case  it would be

$2*cos(t-(3-t))=2*cos(2*t-3)$
am on the right way?or could i simplify way of solution?
EDITED:
so rotation matrix in 2D has form

[image]

Comment: The shape and size of the triangle doesn't change when you rotate it. So rotate it so that $B$ comes to lie on $(1,0)$, and $C$ on $(-1,0)$. Where does that place $A$ then?

Comment: $cos(3),sin(3)$ right? or how rotate?

Comment: @DanielFischer The shape changes.

Comment: @LordSoth Huh? If you rotate a figure, you get a congruent figure.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yea I fell into the same trap. You have $\cos(t)$ and $\cos(3-t)$ one point rotates clockwise, the other rotates counterclockwise, that is why the shape changes.

Comment: @dato No, to rotate $B$ into $(1,0)$, you must rotate the entire figure by an angle of $-t$, so $A$ goes to $\cos (3-2t), \sin (3-2t))$.

Comment: by this way yes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @LordSoth The rotation angle $\vartheta$ is a priori independent of $t$, you get $B \mapsto (\cos (t+\vartheta),\, sin (t+\vartheta))$, $A \mapsto (\cos (3-t+\vartheta,\, \sin (3-t+\vartheta))$, $C \mapsto (\cos (\pi+t+\vartheta),\, \sin (\pi+t+\vartheta))$. Then you choose $\vartheta$ so that $B$ and $C$ go to their respective destinations.

Comment: @DanielFischer what does rotation gives us in our case?i mean how it would be simplified? and why $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$? does it always work for all kind of  parametric  form?

Comment: @dato You then have only one moving point (dependent on $t$), that makes it (IMO) easier to see which $t$ maximises the area.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not see your point. You say the shape of the triangle does not change, and it changes. The area of this triangle is $|\sin(3-2t)|$. Changing $t$ does not rotate the triangle, you get a completely different triangle. If it was merely a rotation, the area would be the same for any $t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, I guess you are talking about rotating for a fixed $t$, my bad.

Comment: @LordSoth Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @DanielFischer  so i should rotate  triangle  right?

Comment: @dato Up to you. I find it simplifies the visualisation, but it may be different for you.

Comment: no, no as much simplify,as more like :D

Comment: i have added matrix,please see it

Comment: what should  be angle of rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: All these points lie on the unit circle. In particular, $B$ and $C$ are antipodal, meaning that the line segment $BC$ passes through the origin. Now, forget about point $A$ as in the problem. Where you should put a point $A'$ such that the area $A'BC$ is maximized, where $BC$ is an antipodal line segment? The solution of this problem is to make $A'BC$ a right triangle (You need to prove this). Now, see if your parametric equations form the same right triangle (up to rotations); and by the way, they will.

Comment: but task is about determine $t$

Comment: I know; I think this is enough hint to keep you going, and you should easily be able to find $t$. Why don't you spend some time on the problem with this hint and let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: i found length of $BC=2$ ,but now i should use Pythagorean theorem  to find length of  $A'B$ right and  point $A'$ itself yes ?,but it will introduce  another variables,maybe  much more right?

Comment: OK, forget about the question. I give you two antipodal points on the unit circle, say $B$ and $C$. As you said, $|BC| = 2$. Your task is to find a point $A'$, again on the unit circle, such that the area $A'BC$ is maximized. Where you should put the point $A'$ and what is the resulting area?

Comment: antipodal means they are on they same line?on diameter? by 180 degree

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point this one?

Comment: triangle which's base is diameter is right triangle

Comment: I edited the answer including a picture of what I am talking about.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090611231338AAg2Tqs

Comment: triangle is equilateral

Comment: @dato Let's go to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9658/discussion-between-dato-and-lord-soth)