# Quadrangle with maximum area in circle

Tags: geometry, circles

My question  is related to my previous one

[find parameter for maximize area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444278/find-parameter-for-maximize-area/444285#444285)

suppose we have  $4$ points,with coordinate

$A(2\cos t,2\sin t)$

$B(-\cos(2-t), -\sin(2-t))$

$C(-2\cos(t) ,-2\sin(t) )$

$D(\cos(2-t),\sin(2-t))$

where  $t\in(0,1)$

we should find such $t$,which maximize area of  quadrangle  $ABCD$.

Now according to my   previous question related to triangle,it has been determined that  if we fix  two point of triangle on diameter and take  third point which would be  equidistant from these two point,then it's area would be  maximum among of other choices,now  suppose that we have done  same to this problem,then where  should i take another two point?

I was thinking  that  such kind of  quadrilateral  would be square,but i think  it should be solved otherwise,maybe we can fix   three point and  choose fourth point so ,that if we represent  area of  quadrilateral as sum of  two triangles,then we should choose fourth point so that  sum of areas of  these two triangles should be  maximum,but how to choose it?what should be angle of rotation?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The set of possible quadruples of vertices is compact and the area is a continuous function of them, hence the maximum is indeed attained.
Any quadrangle that is a non-square can be improved as follows (and hence is not optimal): There must be two adjacent sides of different length, say $|AB|\ne|BC|$. Then replacing $B$ with the point on the tangent parallel to $AC$, i.e. making the triangle $ABC$ isosceles, increases the area simply because the height of the triangle increases while its base $AC$ stays fix.

[image: Area increase is possible with adjacent sides of different length]

Comment: so it means that  area of  our figure can be optimized by maximaze area of each triangle?and when it makes global maximum?

Comment: and also tangent parallel to diagonal $AC$?how it could be

Comment: @dato I added a picture, maybe that makes it clear: Whenever you have two adjacent edges of different length, you can increase the total are beacause you can increase the area of a sub-triangle. The only figure that cannot be increased this way is the one with all sides of equal length, the square